# How can I calculate overall how much power my circuit is using per hour

Tags: power, current-measurement, watts

I have a circuit that has a variable draw of current based on how many revolutions of a wheel is made per hour.

Every other revolution of the wheel my circuit logs data. Which draws around 50 milliamps of current.

I've made this little table to break it down:

*Constants*

```
RPM per one-mph on 27.5 inch wheel = 12.2RPM
Current draw per activation = 50 Milliamps
activation uptime = 10 Milliseconds
```

*Variables*

```
Average speed over 1 hour = 20 mph
RPM @ 20mph = 244 RPM
Revolutions per hour = 14640 RPH
Activations per hour (divide by 2 as im only logging every other)   = 7320 Activations
```

Values

```
Total activation uptime per hour    73.2 Seconds (7320*10/1000)
```

But now im struggling to see how I convert this value into a meaningful value. Given my circuit is running at 5 volts I know that drawing 50 milliamps is going to mean im using 0.25 watts. Do I then multiply this by 73.2? to figure out how many wattseconds im using?

Also from that can I then work out how many milliamp hours this is? The reason im trying to work this out is so that I can spec a battery. I think im close but im getting a bit confused.

Comment: Apologies, but his answer was correct was it not? I can still upvote it :)

Comment: You have a point though, i've unmarked it as an answer until I receive more answers then I can decide which one best answers the question. I just got a bit over excited that I possibly had an answer to a question thats been plaguing me for hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But now im struggling to see how I convert this value into a meaningful value. Given my circuit is running at 5 volts I know that drawing 50 milliamps is going to mean im using 0.25 watts.

Correct.

> Do I then multiply this by 73.2? to figure out how many wattseconds im using?

Yes. (Note that Watt-seconds are also called Joules)

> Also from that can I then work out how many milliamp hours this is?

To get amp-seconds divide by the voltage again; to get milliamp-seconds multiply that by 1000; to get milliamp-hours divide *that* by 3600.

> The reason im trying to work this out is so that I can spec a battery. I think im close but im getting a bit confused.

If your battery isn't 5V I'm guessing you have some sort of voltage converter in-between the data logger and the battery. This calculation will tell you the amount of milliamp-hours drawn from the converter, not from the battery. (If it's a linear regulator they will be the same; if it's a switching regulator they will not be)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. It steps up from 3.7 volts to 5v. So yeah theres an efficiency loss there. They reckon its about 90% efficient, so ill factor that in. I guess im more interested in what the circuit itself is doing. So I guess thats 18.3 Joules

Comment: And approx 5 milliamp hours? If my calculations are correct :)

Comment: Yes, I get about the same answer. (Assuming that's milliamp hours from the battery)

Comment: Also note that "milliamp-hours per hour" is equivalent to average milliamps.

Comment: Then you gain the answer thats fandabbydozy cheers.